# Grails TagLib calling stored body from nested tag

Tags: grails, taglib

We are setting up a generalized tag for table views.

i need to build up the header cols and the content cols.
In order to provide a flexible output for the content cols i want to take use of the tag body.
Otherwise i use the code attribute as a default output.

The strange thing happens in the cell tag:

The first call to

```
//println body?.call(item:[id:4])  // "item 4"
```

results in the expected result.
The second call (wrapped in another closure and temporarily stored in the page scope )

```
//println body?.call(item:[id:4]) // "item"
```

does not take use of the provided closure params.

As it seems in the cell tag

```
println "${body.maximumNumberOfParameters}" // = 1
```

and executed at later point:

```
println "${body.maximumNumberOfParameters}" // = 0
```

Anyone knows more about this situation or internals of GroovyPageTagBody?

Thx in advance.

TagLib:

```
class PageComponentsTagLib{

    def table = { attrs, body ->
        Map model = [:]

        pageScope._v_cols = []
        body()
        model << [columns:pageScope._v_cols]
        pageScope.variables.remove('_v_cols')

        model << [items:attrs.items]
        out << render(template:'/tagLib/p/table', model:model)
    }

    def cell = { attrs, body ->
        //println body?.call(item:[id:4])  // "item 4"
        //println "${body.maximumNumberOfParameters}" // = 1
        pageScope._v_cols << [field:attrs.field, headerLabelCode:attrs.headerLabelCode, content:{ item ->
            //println body?.call(item:[id:4]) // "item"
            //println "${body.maximumNumberOfParameters}" // = 0
            body?.call(item:item)
}]
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <g:each in="${columns}" var="col">
    <th><g:message code="${col.headerLabelCode}"/></th>
    </g:each>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${items}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <g:each in="${columns}" var="col">
      <td>
        <g:set var="_v_b" value="${col.content?.call(item)}"/>
        <g:if test="${_v_b}">
        ${raw(_v_b)}
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
        ${item."${col.field}"}
        </g:else>
      </td>
      </g:each>
    </tr>
    </g:each>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

GSP:

```
<p:table items="${items}">
    <p:cell>
        item ${item?.id}
    </p:cell>
    <p:cell field="actor"/>
    <p:cell field="className"/>
</p:table>
```

Grails Version: 2.4.4

Comment: Got it working. 
It seems like the closure cannot be called correctly outside the tag lib.

So therefore i am populating the content inside the tag lib.


  `Map model = [:]  
  
    pageScope._v_cols = []  
    body()  
    def columns = pageScope._v_cols  
    pageScope.variables.remove('_v_cols')  
  
    model << [columns:columns]  
    model << [rows:attrs.items.collect { item ->  
       columns.collect{ col ->  
           col.content?.call(item:item) ?: item."${col.field}"  
       }  
    }]`